# Varieties whose residue fields do not generate the algebraic closure of the ground field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field, $\overline{K}$ an algebraic closure, and $X$ be a positive dimensional finite type $K$-scheme.

Could there exist a proper subfield $L\subset\overline{K}$ such that the natural inclusion
$$X(L)\hookrightarrow X(\overline{K})$$
is surjective?

If so, what sorts of conditions can we put on $X$ to ensure that this can't happen? I'm also curious about the answer for more general fields $K$.

Comment: You want to add some non-triviality condition ($\dim X>0$ I guess?) to avoid the obvious counterexample $X = \operatorname{Spec} K$.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen thanks, added this condition. Also added the condition that $K$ be a number field, since that’s the case I’m most interested in.

Comment: I assume you mean $K\subseteq L\subseteq \bar{K}$?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the question, but if $X={\rm Spec} K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, then surely $X(L)\neq X(\overline K)$ if $L\neq \overline K$ and otherwise take an affine cover of $X$ and use Noether normalization.

Comment: I agree with Sándor. It even suffices to treat the case of $\mathbb{A}^1$ and use a nonconstant morphism $U\to \mathbb{A}^1$ where $U\subset X$ is an open affine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this never happens: Without loss of generality, $X$ is affine. The case $X=\mathbb{A}^n_K$ is obvious, the general case then follows from Noether normalization and going up.

Comment: Posted independently by [@SándorKovács](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450035/varieties-whose-residue-fields-do-not-generate-the-algebraic-closure-of-the-grou#comment1163016_450035) a few minutes later.  Also, of course, it's obvious for $\mathbb A_K^n$ *as long as $n$ is positive*, as @‍Gro-Tsen [mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450035/varieties-whose-residue-fields-do-not-generate-the-algebraic-closure-of-the-grou#comment1163000_450035).

Comment: Ah, of course. Nice!